# Solving two equations iteratively

Tags: convergence-divergence, nonlinear-system

I am trying to know the conditions under which two non-linear equations, say $f(\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}) = 0$ and $g(\textbf{X},\textbf{Y})=0$ can be solved iteratively. Here both $\textbf{X},\textbf{Y}$ are matrices and the functions $f, g$ contain operations like inverse and determinant.

I can start with a value of $\textbf{X}_0$, find that value of $\textbf{Y}_0$ that satisfies the first equation $f = 0$. Then I use the value of $\textbf{Y}_0$ to solve the equation $g=0$ and find $\textbf{X}_1$. I can continue these iterations to see if the values of $\textbf{X}_n,\textbf{Y}_n$ have converged or not.

I am not sure what are the necessary and sufficient conditions for this sort of approach to have a convergent solution.

Comment: I'm guessing that naive iterative methods like these will work, but a concept similar to "radius of convergence" will govern the successful initial guesses.

Comment: @Displayname: Thanks for the starters. Can you please let me know if you are familiar with any place where I can read up the math behind convergence of these sort of iterative methods?